# Specs2 .await timeout > 1s on CI server

Tags: scala, specs2

I have some specs against a method returning a `Future`. On my local machine the futures complete around 30 to 80ms. On Travis-CI however the build may sometimes fails because a future took more than 1s. (The `.await` method creates a Future matcher that will fail after 1 second).

My first thought it to increase the timeout. I'd like to do it globally for all Specs2 Future matchers in the project. Is that possible? If not, is there's another (perhaps neater) workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `specs2-3.6.4` you can use the [`timefactor`](http://timeFactor%091%09multiply%20all%20durations%20by%20this%20factor%20when%20waiting%20for%20futures) argument to multiply the standard duration (1 second) by a given factor.

Comment: From `  - sbt clean dependencyUpdates coverage test coverageReport`

To `  - sbt clean dependencyUpdates coverage 'test-only -- xonly timefactor 5' coverageReport`

Is that right?

Comment: Yes that should be it.